# Requesting tags for 2 games

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I really want some tags to be added to Arqade. Two of them are [dawn-of-fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-of-fire), and [scrabble](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrabble).

Don't say Scrabble is not online!

Answer (score 2):

Tags need questions in order to exist. If you have a question about these topics, feel free to ask a question, and give it a tag like [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc), and a user with permissions to create tags will come by and create a more appropriate tag for you.

As for [scrabble](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrabble), such questions might be better suited at another site on the network, [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/), but it depends on the specific question. Questions about achievements in a Scrabble mobile game might be on topic here, but questions about the base mechanics of how double word score interacts with double letter score would likely not be.

Comment: On the scrabble point, we do already have individual game tags for scrabble-like clones, such as [Tag:words-with-friends] and [tag:classic-words], but they shouldn't be also tagged [scrabble] If there is an official 'Scrabble' app or digital game, that's when we'd use that tag.